# R data frame copy values in a different empty column

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, rodbc

I’m using RODBC for a database migration. I got a table in the origin, create a data frame and insert in the destination. This is working properly BUT in some cases the columns in the dest are in a different order (i dont know the order) and got an error for the data types.
For example:

```
Col1 Col2 col3
 A1.   B1.  C1
 A2.   B2.  C2
```

In the destination I have:

```
Col3 Col1 Col2
```

I am doing a loop in dest for the colnames (because is the correct order ) and assign the content from orig;

```
Dest[,Col3] <- orig[,Col3]
```

And giving an error because dest has 0 rows.
Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Franchi MuncharaZ. It's almost impossible to guess what the problem is without additional information. [Here you can find important information on how to provide the necessary information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) that helps others to help you.

Comment: But for starters: The error message tells you that `Dest` is an empty data.frame and you are trying to assign a column with at least one row to it.

Comment: yes  @dario ¡, it's and empty data frame and i wanted to populate with the values of other dataframes in a specific order . Thanks for edditing the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dest[names(orig)] <- orig
```